# inserting data to an existing node in xml

Tags: php, html, sql, xml, forms

I'm new to both XML and PHP but I have this project and this is what needs to be done.

I have an html form like this:

```
<table>   
  <tr>
    <td align="right" width="120px">First name:</td>
    <td><input id="txtfname" style="width: 200px" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Last name:</td>
    <td><input id="txtlname" style="width: 200px" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Business name:</td>
    <td><input id="txtbisname" style="width: 200px" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and I have an xml file like this:

```
<data>
    <first_name></first_name>
    <last_name></last_name>
    <business_name></business_name>
</data>
```

is it possible to use a php file to write the data from the html forms to the xml file?
If so, can anyone please tell me how.  I really need to solve this problem.

After this i also need to transfer the xml file to a sql database.

I'm all ears.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It assumes, you have your HTML table in a form and post it to the server.

```
<?php
$str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><data></data>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string( $str );

$fname = trim( $_POST[ 'txtfname' ] );
$lname = trim( $_POST[ 'txtlname' ] );
$bname = trim( $_POST[ 'txtbisname' ] );

$fname = htmlentities( $fname, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false );
$lname = htmlentities( $lname, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false );
$bname = htmlentities( $bname, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false );

$xml->addChild( 'first_name', $fname );
$xml->addChild( 'last_name', $lname );
$xml->addChild( 'business_name', $bname );

$doc = new DOMDocument( '1.0' );
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$doc->loadXML($xml->asXML(), LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
$doc->save( 'data.xml' );
?>
```

Now, `data.xml` is the xml file. Hope this helps.

Comment: Quick question though.  the data displays like this <data><first_name>James</first_name><last_name>Jr.</last_name><business_name>The CEO Club of Pittsburgh</business_name></data>.  But I need it to display like the one on my sample code.

Comment: You are really a life saver. Thanks again @Pushpesh. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I think XSLT is useful for you. Check this out: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Comment: I thought XSLT is just a stylesheet appropriate for xml documents